# reboot: error while loading shared libraries: libip4tc.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: rhel8

I am getting this error while reboot the machine:"reboot: error while loading shared libraries: libip4tc.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

please let me know how to resolve above an error.....

Answer (score 0):

Same question for me, and at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1106718/ubuntu-mate-wont-boot-kernel-panic-not-syncing-and-error-while-loading-sh I reinstalled the  libip4tc0 package using the package manager. The reference describes a manual approach that I did not try:

```
    wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/i/iptables/libip4tc0_1.6.1-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -x libip4tc0_1.6.1-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb /media/ubuntu-mate/ba94799c-*

    wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/lz4/liblz4-1_0.0~r131-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -x liblz4-1_0.0~r131-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb /media/ubuntu-mate/ba94799c-*
```